# How to delete only the last character of a line from a text wideget with Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Recently, I made a dictionary that ask you a string input and show you all the words that have the string in it, and print it in a Text widget. I used for that Tkinter but, every lines, there is a character (IDK what is that chars) and I want to delete it.

```
def dico():
    global dico_search
    global text
    dico = Tk()

    dico.title("dictionnaire français")
    dico.geometry("1024x480")
    dico.config(background='black')
    dico.minsize(480, 360)
    
    scrollbar = Scrollbar(dico)
    text = Text(dico , yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
    scrollbar.config(command=text.yview)
    scrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')
    text.pack(side='left', expand=0, fill='both')
    
    dico_search = Entry(dico, bg="black", fg="white")
    dico_search.pack()
    dico_search_button= Button(dico, text="rechercher",command=search_dico )
    dico_search_button.pack()
    
    
def search_dico():
    global u
    text.delete('1.0', END)
    a=0
    nbr=0
    print('results for the request "',dico_search.get(), '" : ')
    for i in range (len(mots)):
        if dico_search.get() in mots[a]:
            u=""
            u=mots[a]
            text.insert(0.0,u)
            text.delete("", "0.END")
            nbr+=1
        a+=1
```

Thank you

WB

Comment: Do you want to delete it before inserting it into the text widget or after?

Comment: I think before inserting would be better

Comment: Use slicing to remove the last character of any string. `s1 = s[:len(s)-1]`. Here s1 is your new string after removing.

Comment: @DineshKumar: that's way more complex than it needs to be. `s[:-1]` gets all but the last character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to not insert the character rather than insert-and-delete.

```
text.insert("1.0",u[:-1])
```

If you really do want to delete the last character entered in a text widget, you can do it like this:

```
text.delete("end-2c")
```

The "-2c" part means "minus two characters". Minus one character moves the index before the invisible trailing newline, and moving one more character moves the index before the last character.